# Nested GraphQL query with array argument

Tags: graphql, apollo-server

I am using `apollo-datasource-rest` with `apollo-server-lambda` and trying to figure out how to map a query to a specific resolver.  I have the following schema, in which the `plan` query is supposed to return a list of users (that should be driven by the `users` query rather than the `user` query).

```
  type Query {
    user(user_id: String, username: String): User
    users(user_ids: [String!]): [User!]
    plan(plan_id: String): Plan
  }

  type User {
    id: String
    username: String
    first: String
    last: String
    image: String
  }

  type Plan {
    title: String
    image: String
    attending: [User]
  }
```

The `plan` query resolver datasource is as follows:

```
planReducer(data) {
  return {
    image: data.public.info.image,
    title: data.public.info.title,
    attending: Object.keys(data.public.attending)
  }
}
```

`data.public.attending` in the `planReducer` returns an array of `user_id`s that I would like to then be able to feed into my `users` query as opposed to my `user` query.

These are my current resolvers:

```
user: (_, { username }, { dataSources }) =>
  dataSources.userData.getUserByUsername({ username: username }),
users: async (_, { user_ids }, { dataSources }) => {
  const usersArray = await dataSources.userData.getUsersByIds({ userIds: user_ids })
  return usersArray
},
plan: async (_, { plan_id }, { dataSources }) => {
  return dataSources.planData.getPlanById({ planId: plan_id })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your resolver map should look like below:

```
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    plan: async (_parent, { plan_id: planId }, { dataSources }) => (
      dataSources.planData.getPlanById({ planId })
    )
  },
  Plan: {
    users: async ({ user_ids: userIds }, _variables, { dataSources }) => (
      dataSources.userData.getUsersByIds({ userIds })
    )
  }
}
```

Every key within `Query` should be a resolver that corresponds to a query defined within the root `Query` of your schema.  Keys that are direct children of the root, in this case `Plan`, will be used to resolve their corresponding types when returned from the `plan` resolver within `Query`.

If resolvers are not defined, GraphQL will fall back to a default resolver which in this case looks like:

```
const resolvers = {
  Plan: {
    title: (parent) => parent.title,
    image: (parent) => parent.image,
  }
}
```

By specifying a custom resolver, you are able to compute fields to return to your clients based on the return value of parent resolvers.

Comment: This is a great answer.  Thank you.